# User's web path in neo4j-cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a table with user's web path ordered by timestamp:

```
    user_id                             from_page_id        to_page_id          event_type  timestamp
0   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     pages/mine/mine     pv          1598936406406
1   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     /pages/score/score  pv          1598936408261
2   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     pages/mine/mine     click       1598936408311
3   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     /pages/score/score  click       1598936410824
4   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/score/score   /pages/scoreDetai   pv          1598936410878
...
```

I would like to construct the graph of user's web path by:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line
CREATE (p1: Page {url: line.from_page_id, user: line.user_id}), (p2: Page {url: line.to_page_id, user: line.user_id}),
(u)-[:VIEWS]->(p1), (u)-[:VIEWS]->(p2), (p1)-[:NEXT]->(p2);

MATCH (u:User), (p:Page) WHERE u.id = p.user
CREATE (u)-[:VISITS]->(p);
```

But this gives me the user's one event (click) at a time.

[image]

What I want is to output the whole web path with each event/click grouped by session. For example for user ***4906 the first two lines are like one session, from third line starts a new session. We can see that fourth row ends with url (to_page_id): /pages/score/score and fifth row starts with the same url (from_page_id): pages/score/score therefor it's one session just different timestamps.

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Look at https://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2017/07/17/loading-and-analysing-snowplow-event-data-in-Neo4j/

Comment: Is your CSV ordered by timestamp?

Comment: Thanks for that source, I am following it, however I can't get the result I need. Yes, it is ordered by timestamp. And for user ***4906 the first two lines are like one session, from third line starts a new session. We can see that fourth row ends with url (to_page_id): /pages/score/score  and fifth row starts with the same url (from_page_id): pages/score/score therefor it's one session just different timestamps. Following the code in that link constructed graph considers one row as one session, and I am struggling with making it as I explained earlier. Any help/ referring highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Given your data structure, this is a bit tricky, but you could try something like.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line
MERGE (u:User{id:line.user_id})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:VIEWS]->(v)<-[n:NEXT]-()
WHERE NOT (v)-[:NEXT]->()
WITH u, v, n
ORDER BY n.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
FOREACH (i in CASE WHEN v.url = line.from_page_id  THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (p2: Page {url: line.to_page_id})
  CREATE (u)-[:VISITS]->(p2)
  CREATE (v)-[:NEXT{timestamp:line.timestamp, event_type:line.event_type}]->(p2)
)
FOREACH (i in CASE WHEN v.url = line.from_page_id  THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (p1: Page {url: line.from_page_id})
  CREATE (p2: Page {url: line.to_page_id})
  CREATE (u)-[:VISITS]->(p1)
  CREATE (u)-[:VISITS]->(p2)
  CREATE (p1)-[:NEXT{timestamp:line.timestamp, event_type:line.event_type}]->(p2)
)
```

If the "from_page" is equal to the last page the user visited, then it will treat it will only create a to page and connect it to user's web path. If the last visited page is not the same as "from_page", then it will create both the from and to pages. This query assumes that your data is ordered by timestamp ascending.